# search capability using ElasticSearch and NEST Client in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, full-text-search, asp.net-web-api2, nest, elasticsearch-net

I am creating a **asp.net webapi** application with a search capability using **elastisSearch** `( id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net45")` and **NESTclient** `(id="NEST" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net45")`.
I have managed to get basic searching but its only searching full words only. I mean, if I search for the term, “god is good” it will return all the results matching the word “good”, and “god”, and sometimes “is”. Could someone please guide me through on how to write a query that could return results for good with the following terms, **“go”**, **“goo”**, **“good”**, **“goodz”** and even prefix matches, with all the results being highlighted, please. And how would I go about using *typehead.js* and *bloodhood.js* to return suggestions?
This is my implementation so far

**SearchPaper class**

```
public class SearchPaper
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public string UnitName { get; set; }

        public string Course { get; set; }

        public string UnitCode { get; set; }

        public string School { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

**indexing**

```
var paper = new SearchPaper
                {
                    Id = newPaper.PastPaperID,
                    School = newPaper.School,
                    UnitName = newPaper.UnitName,
                    UnitCode = newPaper.UnitCode,
                    Course = _ctx.Courses.Find(newPaper.CourseID).Name,
                    ApplicationUser = _ctx.Users.Find(newPaper.ApplicationUserId).UserName,
                    Description = newPaper.Description
                };


var index = client.Index(paper, i => i
                .Index("epa")
                .Type("paper")
                .Id(newPaper.PastPaperID)
                .Refresh()
                .Ttl("1m")
            );
```

**search**

```
public async Task<IEnumerable> Search(string query)
        {

            var result = client.Search<SearchPaper>(s => s
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .AllIndices()
                .MatchAll()
                .Index("epa")
                .Type("paper")
                .Query(q => q
                    .QueryString(qs => qs
                        .Query(query)))

                .Highlight(h => h
                    .OnFields(f => f
                        //.OnAll()
                        .OnField("*")
                        .PreTags("<em>")
                        .PostTags("</em>")))
            );



            /*
            var result = client.Search<SearchPaper>(s => s
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Query(q => q
                     .Term(p => p.Description, "design")
                )
            );


            var result = client.Search<SearchPaper>(s => s
                .From(0)
                .Size(10)
                .Index("epa")
                .Type("paper")
                .Query(q => q
                     .Term(p => p.Description, query)
                )
            );

            */
            return result.Documents;
        }
```

i really would appreciate if someone could sort me out on this...

Comment: Did you read [NEST tutorial](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example) already? It's a well written article which will help you start with Elasticsearch and NEST.

Comment: hi rob, yes i have. but i am having trouble at this line   `DumpReader = new NugetDumpReader(args[0]);`, so i thought i would read the nest.azurewebsites.net documentation, which have enabled me to get this far. i may wish to look at a complete example of the tutorial, complete with searching, could you combine the different parts of the source code for me for me, please?

Comment: +howdy rob, i have managed to make the example run upto to the point where i start searching...its not searching. no errors, no mistake, index is, i suppose, good....maybe  its the documented error  `NEST 1.x does not yet work on the .NET Core Framework  yet.` ... how do i solve that failure with VS2013, winDOWS 8.1